# Is there a way to retrieve reporting data on individual LinkedIn accounts? Specifically individual users not organizations

Tags: linkedin-api, analytics, bubble.io

I am building an app through Bubble.io and I want to pull individual LinkedIn analytics for specific posts that are published to LinkedIn through my app.

This is possible for organizational accounts, but I can't find any steps for individual accounts. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

My individual users have requested this functionality on my app. They want to see analytic reports for the posts they publish through my site (i.e. number of impressions and number of reactions).

I've spoken with a couple of developers and reached out to LinkedIn and they directed me here.

I've looked at LinkedIn's developers content and couldn't find anything specific to individual users, only organizational users.